# How to connect Laravel Oracle Cloud Database

Tags: oracle, laravel

I have to use Laravel 5.7 with Oracle **Cloud** Database.

I actually have no idea how to do that. I have searched a lot but all instructions that I found are about connecting Laravel with local Oracle Database.

I have already created a database instance on Oracle Cloud and have no idea how to use instance's information in the cloud to make the connection.

Please, I need to know how to connect Laravel 5.7 with Oracle DB.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel does not officialy supports Oracle databases, but you can use a third party driver. Take a look on https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8

Comment: how can I use that package to connect to an Oracle Cloud Database Instance?